# Masking a div with a canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I'm attempting to make a slideshow composed mostly of divs that can be masked by a canvas element (so that it may be in a circle or strange shape, rather than a square. Is this possible? I have seen many examples of masking an image, but not an entire div or collection of divs.

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by "masking"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes its certainly possible to mask divs. For instance a canvas could mask a div like this:

[image]

that's just an image, source here:

http://jsfiddle.net/r58jF/

[or white](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4zL/1/), which it should be noted merely gives the illusion of a circular div and that illusion is highly contingent upon what is in or behind the div

([or something fancier](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4zL/))

Comment: I don't think that "drawing black over all other areas" is the same as "masking". Specifically, I suspect that @Adam wants to make portions of the div content transparent.

Comment: You're probably right, but even so such an effect of making the appearance of portions of div content transparent is possible, insomuch as it is just the illusion of that effect (such as here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4zL/1/, not a true transparency mask but looks transparent enough to the user) which could quite possibly satisfy his need, but that's highly contingent on what he's planning to display. Since he doesn't offer that, I think it is worth offering to him whatever options he might have to achieve that effect.

Comment: I agree; I certainly wouldn't downvote this answer without more answer from the OP :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the rendering of HTML elements as an image source for a canvas, and so you cannot use a canvas to draw the contents of HTML. If you want to make arbitrary portions of a div fully- or partially-transparent, the answer is "No, you cannot do that with a Canvas."